# Magento layout cms.xml file with block cms_index_index does not show cms page content. Why?

Tags: php, magento, layout

I have created a Magento Frontend Package & Theme... I've created a layout/cms.xml file with the following content. On the homepage, there is now the page-title but no content?

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links" before="footer_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <cms_page translate="label">
        <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
                <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>

    <cms_index_index translate="label">
        <label>CMS Home Page</label>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="cms_index_index" template="cms/index/index.phtml" />
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page" />

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
                <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
                <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>

    <cms_index_defaultindex>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="default_home_page" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_defaultindex>

    <cms_index_noroute translate="label">
        <label>CMS No-Route Page</label>
    </cms_index_noroute>

    <cms_index_defaultnoroute>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="default_no_route" template="cms/default/no-route.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_defaultnoroute>
</layout>
```

As you can see there is the `<block type="cms/page" name="cms_page" />` in it, but there is nothing in the frontend. Why? Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get current cms page from Mage:getSingleton
$cms_id = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
$cms_title = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();
$cms_content = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getContent();
```

thanks to http://developerafroz.blogspot.de/2012/01/get-current-cms-page-magentocms-pages.html